# allow acess to multiple google account for same user via Google api

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth

I need to create an app that collects sheets from a user's google drive and do some processing on those sheets periodically. Now, My question is A user in my app may have sheets in spread across multiple google accounts, I need to know how can i store credentials for multiple google accounts for my app's user. Currently i can do this for only one google account

Right now, I am storing credentials i get against my app's user, but the problem is what to do when my app's user needs to use multiple google accounts to upload sheets.

Comment: Can you explain "Currently i can do this for only one google account"? What is stopping you from doing the same thing for multiple accounts?

Comment: I need to know how will the mapping occur? I mean, For a user if i save one credential it is understandable how google will link the correct account, But for multiple, How will google api understand which credential to use for authorisation if I have saved multiple credentials(each for a different google account) for the same user?

Comment: Your app decides which credential to include in each API request. The credential determines which account the API will apply to. Google doesn't care how you manage that.

Comment: Yes, But for a user How do my app know which credential to send in the api request, since I would have stored multiple credential against each user.

Comment: that's an issue for your app to solve depending on how you authenticate your users

Comment: even if the authentication is on email, how do we know at the time of selecting a google account which account is used by the user, whether the registered email or other

Comment: Unfortunately your question is now too broad to be answered. Try to do some research to understand how Google uses OAuth and then come back with specific questions as they arise.